# F# Error FS3033 unsupported DbType 'Structured'

Tags: sql-server, f#, database-connection, dbcontext, dbtype

I’m trying to query our database in F# but I’m having a lot of errors when I get the data context. 
Here is my connection command:

```
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=OCPM;Initial Catalog=Nautilus;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
```

147 errors in total are returned after this simple script, I won’t list them all but here are a couple of examples:

- > Script1.fsx(11,17): error FS3033: The type provider
  >   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
  >   reported an error: Error reading schema. Warning : SQM1025: Unable to 
  >   extract stored procedure 'utvf_VehiclesSummaryUDT' from SqlServer because parameter 'incident' is the unsupported DbType 'Structured'.
- > Script1.fsx(11,17): error FS3033: The type provider
  >   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
  >   reported an error: Error reading schema. Warning : SQM1014: Unable to 
  >   extract stored procedure 'asynch.usp_LBNGBasket' from SqlServer.
  >   Invalid object name '#updatedPriceTab'.

I believe this is due to the complexity of the objects and structures used in our DB. The first error is due to a User-Defined Table Types called `udt_IncidentExposure` in the function `utvf_VehiclesSummaryUDT`. The second is because the temporary table `#updatedPriceTab` is called in `asynch.usp_LBNGBasket` but created in another stored procedures.

I’m surprised of the limited compatibility between F# and SQL Server on complex structures. Is there any other way to connect to SQL server in F#? All I need is doing very simples SQL queries.

Additional information: SQL Server version in use is 10.50.4270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck with using production-quality  [SqlClient type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) because it requires at least SQL2012 to operate.

You may try [SQL Type Provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider), although I do not have any experience using it in production scenarios.

Also you may try using [SqlEntityConnection type provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361035.aspx) that sometimes does better job, than `SqlDataConnection` type provider that you've tried.

And finally, as the last resort, nothing prevents you from accessing SQL from F# through plain ADO.NET.

Comment: I also thought it was an issue with the version of SQL Server but as I’m not an expoert I couldn’t be sure. Thanks for your input.

[SQL Type Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) and [SqlEntityConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361035.aspx) both manage to connect but I’ve got now other issues when I try to query. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try other F# type providers from here: 
http://fsharp.org/guides/data-access/#sql-data-access

The best one (IMO) for MS SQL Server is `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` but I believe it supports only version 2012 and up.